# Kivy: other widgets don't work with TreeVIew , widgets don't respond to clicks

Tags: python, treeview, kivy, filechooser

Trying to make an app with treeview and a menu - action bar, they do show there as you can see in the picture but I can't press them, they don't do anything. I tried with BoxLayout, GridLayout and FloatLayout and nothing changed. Also tried after calling "set_current_user" function to remove the widget and create it again but no success with it, any idea how to solve it? Thank you!

```
<CloudView>:
name: "cloud"
id: cloud_view
on_pre_enter: root.set_current_user()
tv: tv
actionmenu: actionmenu
my_layout: my_layout
GridLayout:
    id: my_layout
    rows: 3
    TreeView:
        id: tv
    Button:
        text: 'hhh'
        on_release: root.do_something()
    ActionBar:
        id: actionmenu
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Action Bar'
                with_previous: False
                on_release: root.do_something()
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn0'
                on_release: root.do_something()
                icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn1'
                on_release: print('Btn1 Pressend')
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn2'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Group 1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn3'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn4'
            ActionGroup:
                dropdown_width: 200
                text: 'Group 2'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn5'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn6'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn7'
```

class CloudView:

```
class CloudView(Screen, BoxLayout, GridLayout):
tv = ObjectProperty(None)
actionmenu = ObjectProperty(None)
copy = ''
cut = ''
global current_user

def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    super(CloudView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.actionmenu = ActionBar()
    self.add_widget(self.actionmenu)
    self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='My Cloud'),
                       hide_root=False,
                       indent_level=4, )
    populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, self.show_cloud())
    self.add_widget(self.tv)
    self.selected = ''
    self.previous = None


def show_cloud(self):
    s.send('CLOUD'.encode('utf-8'))
    print('yes')
    if current_user is None:
        print('default')
        s.send('default'.encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        s.send(current_user.encode('utf-8'))
        print(current_user)
    file_system = pickle.loads(s.recv(4096))
    return file_system.get_tree()

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    node = self.tv.get_node_at_pos(touch.pos)
    if not node:
        return
    if node.disabled:
        return
    # toggle node or selection ?
    if node.x - self.tv.indent_start <= touch.x < node.x:
        self.tv.toggle_node(node)
    elif node.x <= touch.x:
        self.tv.select_node(node)
        self.selected = self.tv.selected_node
        print(self.get_path(self.selected))
        node.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)
    return True

def set_current_user(self):
    print('in')
    if current_user != self.previous:
        self.remove_widget(self.tv)
        #self.remove_widget(self.actionmenu)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='My Cloud'),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4, )
        populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, self.show_cloud())
        self.add_widget(self.tv)
        #self.add_widget(self.create_action())
        print('done')


def sign_out(self):
    self.manager.current = 'main'

def upload_files(self):
    self.manager.current = 'user_file_manager'

def copy_f(self):
    self.copy = self.get_path(self.selected)
    self.cut = ''

def cut_f(self):
    self.cut = self.get_path(self.selected)
    self.copy = ''

def paste(self):
    s.send('PASTE'.encode('utf-8'))
    s.send(current_user.encode('utf-8'))
    if self.copy == '':
        if self.cut == '':
            pass
        else:
            s.send('CUT'.encode('utf-8'))
            s.send(self.cut.encode('utf-8'))
            s.send(self.get_path(self.selected).encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        s.send('COPY'.encode('utf-8'))
        s.send(self.copy.encode('utf-8'))
        s.send(self.get_path(self.selected).encode('utf-8'))

def rename(self):
    show_popup('RENAME')

def get_path(self, node):
    parent = node.parent_node
    list_path = [node.text]
    while parent is not None:
        list_path.append(parent.text)
        parent = parent.parent_node
    final_path = 'C:\\RonCloud'
    for i in range(len(list_path)-2, -1, -1):
        final_path = final_path + '\\' + list_path[i]
    return final_path
```

how it looks like
[image: how it looks]

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi edited! Any idea what to do?